# Which line(s) of the following code would give an error:

Tags: java, operator-precedence

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

int a=10,b=20;

System.out.println(a+++--b);//line 1

System.out.println(a--+++b);//line 2

System.out.println(a++-++b);//line 3

System.out.println(a+++++b);//line 4

}
```

I am getting error for line 2 and line 4 but, i am not getting how.

Comment: If poorly formatted code gives you an error you don't understand, the first step is to improve the formatting. That usually helps you in understanding the error.

Comment: so, you get an error... why not reading the error message?

Comment: apply some spaces, and use ';' instead of ':' will solve quite a few of your problems I'm guessing

Comment: it is giving me the operator error which i am not able to understand.

Comment: @Stultuske now check

Comment: as I said before, add some spaces. try changing a--+++b into: a-- + ++b, for instance

Comment: Great question, this is an interesting topic.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" occurs during tokenization (i.e. transforming the input into a sequence of tokens that the compiler then uses to analyze the code structure.)

The [JLS 3.2. Lexical Translations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) says:

> [...]
>
> 3. A translation of the stream of input characters and line terminators resulting from step 2 into a sequence of input elements (§3.5) which, after white space (§3.6) and comments (§3.7) are discarded, comprise the tokens that are the terminal symbols of the syntactic grammar (§2.3).
>
> The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.

And that means that sequences like

```
a--+++b
a+++++b
```

is transformed into tokens as if you had written

```
a -- ++ + b
a ++ ++ + b
```

which then (due to operator precedence) forms

```
((a--)++) + (b)
((a++)++) + (b)
```

But `a--` and `a++` are values and you cannot apply a further `++` operator to a value.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, your lines are being interpreted as follows.

```java
System.out.println(a++ + --b);//line 1
System.out.println(a--++ + b);//line 2
System.out.println(a++ - ++b);//line 3
System.out.println(a++++ + b);//line 4
```

It would appear the compiler is going to extrapolate in a left-to-right manner.

Essentially, it can deduce the operators on lines 1 and 3, since ++ +, and ++ -, are logical sequences.
While, the operators on lines 2 and 4 prove illogical.

It's unsure where to place the +, either as an arithmetic operator, or towards *b* as a unary operator.
Thus, it stops and throws an error.

If you were to parse in a right-to-left manner, you'd be able to resolve the statements.

```
a-- + ++b
a++ + ++b
```